# Найти в текстовом файле

Tags: python, python-3.x, поиск, текст

Есть .doc файл, в нем надо найти все email(gmail,mail,ya.ru и т.д), но я так и не понял как это сделать? Попробовал вот такую штуку

```
from __future__ import print_function
import io
word = '@'
with io.open('/home/aprokurov/test.doc', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:
        if word in line:
            print(line, end='')
n = '+7'
with io.open('/home/aprokurov/test.doc', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:
        if n in line:
          print(line, end='')
```

Но эта программа будет печатать всю строку когда надо вывести именно сам маил и номер телефона, как заставить печатать именно мэйл и номер телефона?

Comment: Не могли бы Вы приложить входные данные? Что у Вас в `.doc` файле?

Comment: используйте регулярные выражения. Модуль    're'  для разбора строки.
шаблоны для телефона и е-мєйла можно найти в интернете.
так будет больше пользы чем прочесть готовый ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно воспользоваться регулярными выражениями. Шаблон, по которому будем искать e-mail я взял с [этого](http://emailregex.com/) сайта, убрав из него условие, что в строке должен быть только адрес без другого текста. Найти все подстроки по шаблону можно методом `findall` из модуля `re`.

```
from re import findall
l = ['text text mail@mail.ru', 'text text mail@mail.ru text text',
     'mail@mail.ru', 'text mail@127.0.0.1 text',
     'text mail@127.0.0.1 text mail@mail.ru', 'text text text']
pattern = r"([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)"
for i in l:
    print(findall(pattern, i))
```

Вывод:

```
['mail@mail.ru']
['mail@mail.ru']
['mail@mail.ru']
['mail@127.0.0.1']
['mail@127.0.0.1', 'mail@mail.ru']
[]
```

Comment: можно же `\w+`, что-то пошло не так :)

Comment: В смысле? В адресе электронной почты может быть много сюрпризов.

Comment: В принципе, да, затупил.

Comment: в вопросе еще номер телефона просили )))
Кроме того в адресе могут быть поддиректории ;-)
А сайт - может содержать кириллицу - в общем - вопрос "не детский" =D

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/company/yandex/blog/109278/
вот допустимый адрес:
 ivan@марья.рф